# Running Springgboot application with Embedded tomcat Server

Tags: tomcat

First application is is developed in springboot 2.0.5 version and war file deployed over the external tomcat Server.

While trying to run the same application with tomcat embedded server,sometimes values are not getting picked from properties file.some properties are not getting picked while starting application with Springgboot:run command.if we pass those arguments with -d argument application is starting with embedded tomcat Server .

But if you hit any service soap or rest from soap ui tool getting invalid-content-type:text/html .please help me in resolving this issue .
Kind regards,
ShaikReddipeer

Comment: Springboot *is* a Tomcat server - it makes no sense to put it into another Tomcat server.

Comment: Spring Boot is not a "Tomcat server". It has an embedded Tomcat as a dependency, which is completely optional. You may swap it with Jetty or completely exclude it from dependencies, build the application as a war file and deploy it on an external server (which is what the OP did previously). This way is less common (probably this is why the OP is migrating away from it), but it has its benefits.

Comment: It's really hard to answer your question as it's very vaguely formulated. Please add some details on your setup (e.g. where is your property file located, how exactly do you run the application, what does "sometimes" mean in "sometimes properties are not getting picked" (are they getting picked 50% of the time, 10% of the time?), whether there are any errors in the logs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with a profile

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev
```